# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'answer' when try to get the latest record with Q filter

Tags: django

```
>>> from rabbit.models import TrackBot
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> latest_send = TrackBot.objects.filter(~Q(sender=110069554021986) & Q(is_postback=True))
>>> latest_send
<QuerySet [<TrackBot: 4d0f034b-f067-4c83-a0f1-92624439c880>]>
>>> latest_send.sender
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sender'
>>>
```

## How to get the field value ?

### UPDATED:

I solved this by add .lastest() like this

```
passed_step1 = TrackBot.objects.filter(~Q(sender=110069554021986) & Q(is_postback=True) & Q(qcode=CONST_QCODE1)).latest('updated_at')
```

Comment: It means there is no record that satisfies the filter, so `.first()` returns `None`.

Comment: can you help to check my update question? thanks